# jQuery mobile: disable list split

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I would like to insert some additional links(actually, 'tags' to show to which categories belongs each item) in every item in my list, but when I do that, first one renders not like the tag that I want, but addition clickable section on the left side of list item, exactly as it shown in [this](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-split.html) example. How to disable this feature?

```
<div data-role="content">   
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="a">
        <li data-role="list-divider">{{header}}</li>
        {% for item in g.previews %}
            <li><a href="{{item[0]}}">  
                <h3 class="ui-li-heading">{{item[1]}}</h3>  
                <p class="ui-li-desc">{{item[2]}}</p></a>
                <div style="display:inline-block;">
                {% for tag in item[3] %}
                    <div class="tag"><a href="{{ tag[0] }}">{{ tag[1] }}</a></div>
                {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </li>  
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: First show us your HTML and what have you tried to do.

Comment: @Gajotres I have added code, as you could see - I have tried to wrap tags with some additional div, but no success.